# how to get pgpool2 HA

Tags: postgresql-9.3, high-availability, pgpool

I am using pgpool2 and PostgreSQL to get a HA of postgresql service. I have been working in this:

```
  .-----.                  .--------.
  |     |           W      |   DB   |
  | PGP |-----+----------->| MASTER |----.
  |     |     |            |        |    |
  `-----`     |            `--------`    | STREAMING REPLICATION
              |            .--------.    |
              |     R      |   DB   |    |
              +----------->| SLAVE1 |<---+      
              |            |        |    |
              |            `--------`    |
              |            .--------.    |
              |     R      |   DB   |    |
              `----------->| SLAVE2 |<---`
                           |        |
                           `--------`
after failover of Master:

  .-----.                  .--------.
  |     |                  |   DB   |
  | PGP |-----+----        | MASTER |
  |     |     |            |  FAIL  |
  `-----`     |            `--------`
              |            .--------.
              |    W/R     |   DB   |
              +----------->| SLAVE1 |---.          
              |            |        |   |
              |            `--------`   |
              |            .--------.   | STREAMING REPLICATION
              |     R      |   DB   |   |
              `----------->| SLAVE2 |<--`
                           |        |
                           `--------`
```

I have one pgpool (PGP) host, one Master (M) and two Slaves (SLAVE1 and SLAVE2) also called S1 and S2.

When M fail S1 is promoted to master and S2 point to it. And I keep doing my queries to PGP. Everything is ok.

But I have thinking and researching, without result, in how can I get a High Availability (HA) with my PGP machine. It is fail, all my system become critical.

But I want, after failover of Mater and after failover of PGP a second pgpool machine (PGP2) to get the HA of my pgpool service.

```
  .-----.                  .--------.
  |     |                  |   DB   |
  | PGP |-----+----        | MASTER |
  |     |     |            |  FAIL  |
  `-----`     |            `--------`
              |            .--------.
              |    W/R     |   DB   |
              +----------->| SLAVE1 |---.          
              |            |        |   |
              |            `--------`   |
              |            .--------.   | STREAMING REPLICATION
              |     R      |   DB   |   |
              `----------->| SLAVE2 |<--`
                           |        |
                           `--------`
after failover:

  .-----.                  .--------.
  |     |                  |   DB   |
  | PGP |  |--+----        | MASTER |
  |     |  |   |           |  FAIL  |
  `-----`  |   |           `--------`
           |   |            .--------.
      >----+   |    W/R     |   DB   |
   .--|--.     +----------->| SLAVE1 |---.          
   |     |     |            |        |   |
   | PGP2|     |            `--------`   |
   |     |     |            .--------.   | STREAMING REPLICATION
   `-----`     |      R     |   DB   |   |
               `----------->| SLAVE2 |<--`
                            |        |
                            `--------`
```

I have been looking in many posts and blogs but I always find the HA of PostgreSQL services using pgpool, but:

How do I get the HA of pgpool hosts?

I was studying something about watchdogs with pgpool, but I am still lost !!